# add decrypted javascript inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add decrypt javascript and it is not working

```
    var decrypedjs = "alert(\"test\")" //for example;
    function start() {
    decrypedjs
    };
```

and the html

```
<button onclick="start()">started</button>
```

i have looked at so many sources and what i am finding is not really helpful or not working.

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript); 
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "decrypt javascript"? It looks like you're trying to execute an arbitrary string as JS code is that right? Can you clarify exactly what doesn't work about that second example and provide enough context for it to be runnable (maybe some markup, and clarification on what `target` is)

Comment: I have some code to decrypt and encrypt and i want to make it so that it can decrypt that code and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on any security point other than to not use eval with external sourced strings (post-, get parameters, etc), but you're looking for the eval method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```js
    var decrypedjs = "alert(\"test\")" //for example;
    
    function start() {
      eval(decrypedjs);
    };
    
    start();
```